# Member state of first entry on Croatia visa aplication

Tags: schengen, transit, schengen-visas

I will be travelling to Zagreb via Frankfurt from India. On the visa application form, it asks for a 'member state of first entry'. Will this be Frankfurt or Zagreb?

We only have a 1-hour layover at Frankfurt, so I doubt we have time for immigration there.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this be Frankfurt or Zagreb?

You will have entry immigration done in Frankfurt

Both Germany and Croatia are part of the Schengen Area, Frankfurt-Zagreb is therefore a intra-Schengen flight, so you will enter the Area in Frankfurt.

> so I doubt we have time for immigration there.

I wouldn't worry, if this is a single ticket, the airline will rebook you on the next flight if you fail to make it.

If it is on two separate tickets, it is impossible to achieve.

Comment: "If it is on two separate tickets, it is impossible to achieve." Not necessarily. If the airlines interline, luggage will be checked in all the way. Been there done that. HKG-FRA on CX, FRA-NUR on LH, 2 separate tickets. Smooth as silk. Stayed airside.

Answer (score 2):

> We only have a 1-hour layover at Frankfurt, so I doubt we have time for immigration there.

You have it backwards. It should read

> ​We only have a 1-hour layover at Frankfurt, so I doubt we have time for transfer, because security and immigration will eat up a lot of time.

You have no choice but pass through Immigration in Frankfurt. Depending on the time of arrival, security, and then Immigration, could take a lot of time, or be quick enough. I was there early this week, and landed at 07:00. A few Asian flights, so security was packed. Immigration was swift, but then again I have a French passport, so I used the automated gates.